# Spliterator generated by Iterables.partition() doesn't behave as expected?

Tags: java, java-stream, guava, partition, spliterator

I've noticed that the spliterator produced by using Guava's `Iterables.partition(collection, partitionSize).spliterator()` behaves strange.

Executing trySplit() on the resultant spliterator doesn't split, but executing trySplit() on the result of the initial trySplit() finally does.

Furthermore, using `StreamSupport.stream(Iterables.partition(collection, partitionSize).spliterator(), true)` does not parallelize the the stream, but
`StreamSupport.stream(Iterables.partition(collection, partitionSize).spliterator().trySplit(), true)` does parallelize and the resultant stream contains all of the partitions.

My goal is: given a collection with size 100k I want to partition it into batches of size 5000 and process those batches in parallel.

2 questions: does the spliterator generated by Iterables.partition behave correctly?
Is my approach a good way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Shouldn't it print 1 after trySplit() is called? before trySplit() is called I agree the spliterator should be of size 2. But after the split it should reduce to 1.

Counter example:
```List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
        Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = numbers.spliterator();
        System.out.println(spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown()); //prints 2
        System.out.println(spliterator.trySplit().getExactSizeIfKnown()); //prints 1```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, so what does the initial trySplit() on the spliterator returned by ```Iterables.partition``` do then? and why doesn't ```StreamSupport.stream(Iterables.partition(collection, partitionSize).spliterator(), true)``` behave as a SIZED spliterator would?

Comment: I deleted the comments and will try to post an answer soon, I understood where your struggle is...

Comment: When you can invoke `trySplit` on the result of the initial `trySplit`, it implies that the initial `trySplit` did return a non-`null` value. So it *did* split, as you have two `Spliterator` instances afterwards. Maybe it’s not balanced, but balanced splitting is desired, not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Spliterator` comes from an `Iterable`, that does not have a known size. So the implementation internally will buffer the elements into a buffer of size `1024` and continue to increase the buffer on next iterations. What I mean by that is :

```
    List<Integer> coll = IntStream.range(0, 150_000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Iterable<List<Integer>> it = Iterables.partition(coll, 1);
    Spliterator<List<Integer>> sp = it.spliterator();

    Spliterator<List<Integer>> one = sp.trySplit();
    System.out.println(one.getExactSizeIfKnown());

    Spliterator<List<Integer>> two = sp.trySplit();
    System.out.println(two.getExactSizeIfKnown());

    Spliterator<List<Integer>> three = sp.trySplit();
    System.out.println(three.getExactSizeIfKnown());

    Spliterator<List<Integer>> four = sp.trySplit();
    System.out.println(four.getExactSizeIfKnown());
```

which would print:

```
1024
2048
3072
4096
```

If you want to process `5000` elements at a time, you need to start with a `Spliterator` that has a known size to begin with. You could put those partitions to an `ArrayList` first:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> coll = IntStream.range(0, 15_000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Iterable<List<Integer>> it = Iterables.partition(coll, 5000);

    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    it.forEach(list::add);

    StreamSupport.stream(list.spliterator(), true)
            .map(x -> {
                System.out.println(
                        "Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                        " processed elements in the range : " + x.get(0) + " , " + x.get(x.size() - 1)
                );
                return x;
            })
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

On my machine it shows that they are processed by one thread each:

```
Thread : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5 processed elements in the range : 10000 , 14999
Thread : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19 processed elements in the range : 0 , 4999
Thread : main processed elements in the range : 5000 , 9999
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any color on how ```StreamSupport.stream(<unsized spliterator>, true)``` works? Does this ```StreamSupport.stream``` method only trySplit() once in general?

Comment: @MykolasT wait, wasn't that explained in the first part of the answer? With buffering...?

Comment: That part I get and it's very interesting. My comment is just to clarify on the behaviour of ```StreamSupport.stream```. Assuming we are dealing with 20 partitions they would all go into the initial buffer after one ```trySplit()```, thus the original spliterator would be 'empty' and the one generated by the trySplit() would have all of them, would be sized, and therefore fairly 'splittable'. Given that if you just pass the unsized spliterator into ```StreamSupport.stream``` the stream is effectively not parallelized, does that imply that ```StreamSupport.stream``` only splits once?

Comment: @MykolasT well yes, _that_ Spliterator will split only once, and next invocations on the original one, will return `null`, meaning "no more splits are possible". It does not mean it's empty ( though it is in your case ), it could have less elemenets the the needed buffer, thus no splits, but still has elements.